# Database Connection issues with liquibase ?

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I am to run ddls using changeset and further step is to deploy binaries but before that liquibase is not consistent with connection.Because of this continuous deployment is happening.

```
  INFO 10/6/16 4:21 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
    INFO 10/6/16 4:21 PM: liquibase: Reading from SOLSTAIR2$OWNER.DATABASECHANGELOG
    INFO 10/6/16 4:21 PM: liquibase: TairdatabaseChangeLog.xml: TairdatabaseChangeLog.xml::rel1::solstis: SQL in file LiquibaseRelease/ddl_table1.sql executed
    INFO 10/6/16 4:21 PM: liquibase: TairdatabaseChangeLog.xml: TairdatabaseChangeLog.xml::rel1::solstis: ChangeSet TairdatabaseChangeLog.xml::rel1::solstis ran successfully in 32ms
    INFO 10/6/16 4:21 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
    Liquibase Update Successful
    generating SQL for review
    Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    SEVERE 10/6/16 4:23 PM: liquibase: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:53)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:849)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:170)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:89)
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:231)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:141)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:44)
    ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:682)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:711)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:558)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:223)
    ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:96)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:209)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:215)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:302)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
```

Comment: Your socket connection (to the database) is reset. This probably doesn't have anything to do with liquibase. One more thing: Where is that "generating SQL for review" coming from?

Comment: What is the reason to reset socket connection ?.generating SQL for review is part of liquibase while running

Comment: I have no clue what the reason for socket reset is. 
But I have doubts that "generating SQL for review" is a direct part of liquibase. I think "Liquibase Update Successful" is one of last messages that liquibase generates when you run the `update` command. The "generating SQL for review" is misterious to me...